# Facebook app clean notifications and badge.How?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ios7

I work on application, that uses Remote Notifications, and I am curious about something:

I notice, that Facebook app cleans notifications and application badge, when you read it in browser,even if you killed an app from app switcher.That happens when friend add something in your timeline.

So my question is: How this is done?

My understanding is when Application is killed from App switcher it goes into suspended state and cannot execute code.Is it possible to do this in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand they just are sending push notification with badge number set to 0.

Comment: Ok, but how notification/alert is clean then?

Comment: Sending 0 as badge number clears notifications from Notifications Center as I understand